# Gif Animation Stops When Dynamically Generating HTML

Tags: jquery, html, animation, animated-gif

I see many discussions about .gif animations no longer animating during AJAX calls, the result of the asynchronous nature of AJAX. I think my issue is different: I am dynamically generating HTML on click and want to have a standard stopwatch animation play in a modal fashion until the HTML is created. Showing and hiding the animation is easy enough -- once I click something, I add the class that will display the animation:

`$("#something").click(function(){
   $("body").addClass("loading");
   htmlCreate(); // the function dynamically generating the HTML
});`

And reverse the process at the end of the dynamic HTML generation:

`$("body").removeClass("loading");`

The image definitely displays, but never animates. I read one post here suggesting the image has to fully load before it can animate, so I tried something like:

`$body.addClass("loading");
   setTimeout(function() {
      htmlCreate();
   }, 2000);`

And this definitely gives me two seconds of animation, which stops as soon as setTimeout times out and the `htmlCreate()` function is invoked. The process of dynamically building the HTML is definitely a process monster -- Chrome shows over 90% of CPU usage on my not-slow Macbook while `htmlCreate()` is running -- so I could easily see it overwhelming the browser and preventing it from fully displaying all the animated frames in the .gif. But if someone can recommend a solution, I'd be most grateful. Thanks for your attention and assistance.

Comment: What does the CSS for loading look like?

Comment: `body.loading .modal { display: block !important; }`, which works fine. As I say, the .gif does indeed animate during the setTimeout prior to `htmlCreate();` being invoked, and displays the .gif in a frozen state for the rest of the time `htmlCreate();` runs. I don't this is a style issue.

Comment: What does htmlCreate do? typically html manipulation doesn't stop gifs, however synchronous ajax requests will. If you're just manipulating html and not doing ajax and it's stopping the gif, maybe you need to optimize the html manipulation a bit.

Comment: `htmlCreate` does alot (and it's too big to reproduce here) -- it retrieves JSON from localStorage and generates hundreds of lines of very involved HTML via loops based on limits determined at run time. I'd say it's particularly well-optimized for the task it accomplishes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which i probably (i forgot) fixed with reloading src tag of img

```
$(".myimg").attr("src", $(".myimg").attr("src"));
```

Comment: maybe i completely replace img

Comment: Where would you do that, based on my code snippets?

Comment: i did not correctly understand your question. my problem was in showing image from hidden state. looks like your script completely overload browser. optimize htmlCreate, use less jQuery - clear js can works up to 10x time faster.